# Magento 2: add custom field to shipping and billing address at checkout page and save it in admin side sales order

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I want to add to custom fields to the shipping and billing area of the checkout page. When a user clicks on place order it should be saved and display in admin side sales order page. Here I saw You below image.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: check with this - https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/